# Displaying win message after the first counter is placed

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a connect four in VB but every time the user put where they would like the counter it displays the win message when it should display after at least four counters, how come it is doing this? Fairly new to VB

```
    Dim check1 As Integer = 0
    Dim check2 As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5
        If stackTable1(i) = turnCounter = False Then
            check1 = check1 + 1

        ElseIf stackTable1(i) = turnCounter = True Then
            check2 = check2 + 1

        End If

        If check1 = 4 Then
            MsgBox("you win player one!")
        End If
        If check2 = 4 Then
            MsgBox("you win player two!")
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Did you mean `stackTable1(i) <> turnCounter`?

Comment: @LarsTech Im trying to use the Boolean value of either true or false to then count up but the program is just instantly saying you win and seems to missing the code completely

Comment: Either put the statement before in brackets `(stackTable1(i) = turnCounter) = False` or just use the actual _not equal to_ operator (Like Lars suggested, which is the recommended way of doing it): `stackTable1(i) <> turnCounter`.

Comment: What a great chance to learn about the debugger and *expressions*